# Function pageExist(); always returns false

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I'm still improving my template engine, and now I'm at the part that's going to see if the requested page actually exists. Please take a look at the following function:

```
public function pageExist( $id )
{
    $query = $this->db->connection->prepare( 'SELECT id FROM ' . $this->functions->prefix( 'pages' ) . ' where id = ?' );
    $query->bind_param( 'i', $id );
    $query->execute();
    if ( $query->num_rows > 0 )
    {
        return true;
    } 
        else
    {
        return false;
    }
    $query->close();
}
```

But the proplem is, it always returns false, so is there anything wrong with my prepared statement or anything?

I call a page with ID `1`, I don't know if that has anything to do with it, but as it might help, I'll just state it.

Thanks.

Comment: There can never be a row with id of 0. Database tables must start at 1 if an integer. This will return false as no rows will be found.

Comment: Are you sure your SQL is valid? `$this->functions->prefix( 'pages' )` looks suspiciously like it generates a prefix only, not a full table name.

Comment: @EdCottrell It will return the prefix, set in another file, followed by the table name given, in this case, it'll return `ws_pages`. I've tested it.

Comment: @W.H.E.Peeters hard code the whole query in the prepare including the value for id; comment out the parameter binding; see if you actually get a valid response.

Comment: @W.H.E.Peeters In that case, I'm 99% sure your problem is that you call `$query->close()` *after* you return from the function, so that call is never executed.  That results in the database connection being in an unusable state the next time you try to use it.  Try pasting that line before each of your return statements and make sure you close all other open statements. If that works, I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: P.S. Obviously, also make sure there really is a page with id `1`... :)

Comment: Actually one other thing to check is to make sure the connection is not failing; I'm curious what msqli_error is returning on that object.

Comment: @Shawn It actually outputs nothing...

Comment: @EdCottrell I did make sute that the ID is `1`, and it's also not the `$query->close();`, going to try Shawns' hardcoding solution now.

Comment: @Shawn The Hardcoding solution doesn't work either. I made a quick screen of my database: http://wesleypeeters.nl/img/66332-14-08-2014_00:11:02.png

Comment: @W.H.E.Peeters If the query is correct and the prepare is not working then the only thing that makes sense is that you are not correctly connecting to the database (the database object is null), or the connection has not persisted.

Comment: @Shawn I already tested it when I made the connection for the first time like this: `throw new Exception($this->connection->errno, 1);` And ofcourse an if statement to check if there is an error

Comment: $this->connection->errno... but in your code it is $this->db->connection; should it just be $this->connection?

Comment: @Shawn it's because that code is in another file, I passed through the connection using a `__construct()` function

Comment: Just for now. Move all connection info right into this function. If we can guarantee a result is returned; then we can figure out something higher in the stack.

Comment: @Shawn How will I do that is the DB connection is in another class?

Comment: Try executing all this code in a flat file. $conn = mysqli_connect('...'); $conn->prepare('...') something along those lines

Comment: @Shawn Same result..

Comment: @W.H.E.Peeters I'm not really sure how to debug this further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before accessing `mysqli_stmt::$num_rows`, you must call `mysqli_stmt::store_result()`.  See [mysqli_stmt::$num_rows on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

Excerpt:

> Returns the number of rows in the result set. The use of mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the statement handle.
>
> If you use mysqli_stmt_store_result(), mysqli_stmt_num_rows() may be called immediately.

Try this:

```
public function pageExist( $id )
{
    $query = $this->db->connection->prepare( 'SELECT id FROM ' . $this->functions->prefix( 'pages' ) . ' where id = ?' );
    $query->bind_param( 'i', $id );
    $query->execute();
    // Call store_result() before accessing num_rows.
    $query->store_result();
    if ( $query->num_rows > 0 )
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    $query->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can never be a row with id of 0. Database tables must start at 1 if an integer. This will return false as no rows will be found.

Comment: It still, automaticly, returns false. The ID is now 1. Still, thanks for the answer!

Comment: What ids actually exist in the table?

Comment: Just 1, since this is a test run.

Comment: You do know that that is a `i` on purpose? Since it indicates it's a integer?

Comment: What library are you using? PDO, mysqli?

Comment: Mysqli, I'm sorry, I forgot to state that.